# How do I use the dollar sign ina C string?

Tags: c, windows, powershell

How can I print the dollar sign $ in the following code or any string for that matter?

```
system("powershell -executionpolicy unrestricted -file \"$env:userprofile\\Desktop\\Test.ps1\"");
```

Comment: `system` doesn't print stuff. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: @corn3lius: The $ character does not need to be escaped...

Comment: The problem is that the $ sign is missing when it returns the error: 'Processing -File ':userprofile\Desktop\Test.ps1' failed: the path not of a legal form. Specify a valid path.'

Comment: @MikeKwan: Can you show me how I might modify this to make it work? Thanks...

Comment: @AndrewRynhard: I can only tell you that the problem is not with the string. See this example: http://codepad.org/AwxdzVug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$env is PowerShell variable.
use getenv in c
or
use %%USERPROFILE%% (BATCH(shell:cmd.exe) variable)

E.g

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void){
    char *userprofile;
    char command[1024];
    userprofile = getenv("USERPROFILE");
    sprintf(command, "powershell -executionpolicy unrestricted -file \"%s\\Desktop\\Test.ps1\"", userprofile);
    system(command);
    //or
    system("powershell -executionpolicy unrestricted -file \"%%USERPROFILE%%\\Desktop\\Test.ps1\"");
    return 0;
}
```